# I am using TiddlyWiki Classic and I want to add "newTiddler" button "ToolbarCommands"

Tags: javascript, tiddlywiki

I am currently using TiddlyWiki Classic and I want to add the "newTiddler" button into ToolbarCommands so that it is present on all tiddlers. I also just feel like it should be with those buttons. I tried just adding "newTiddler" into the ToolbarCommands, but it just does not work. Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't just add a macro into toolbar since toolbar is a separate macro, not a transclusion. You have to create a new command (below I'm writing JS code that you should use as a plugin):

```
config.commands.newTiddler = {
    text: "new tiddler", // or whatever you want to see on the button
    tooltip: "Create a new tiddler",
    handler: function(event,src,title) {

        var currentTiddler = story.getTiddler(title);
        story.displayTiddler(
            currentTiddler, // to open it below the current tiddler; if you want it on top, put null instead
            config.macros.newTiddler.title, // default title, you may use anything you want
            DEFAULT_EDIT_TEMPLATE // you may use a custom one, though
        );
    }
};
```

Just create a tiddler (like NewTiddlerToolbarPlugin), put the code there, tag it `systemConfig`, restart TW and add the new command (`newTiddler`) to the ToolbarCommands.

Comment: You can also get some help at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tiddlywikiclassic